# Gauss Law Not Working Inside Cavity

Tags: electrostatics

When I apply gauss law inside a cavity within uniformly charged solid sphere then I get  that

$$\oint E.dA =Q _{enclosed}/{\epsilon_{0}}$$

Which should imply that $E=0$ since enclosed charge is 0.

But my book states electric field inside the cavity is not 0.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: which book?section and page number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Gauss' law says is that the flux is zero. You can't say anything about the electric field at a given point with Gauss' law unless there is some sort of symmetry, say spherical, cylindrical, or planar. So, unless the cavity is spherical, and is centered smack dab in the middle of the charged sphere, we can't say anything. If this is the case however, then the field would be every where zero inside the cavity.

Comment: No no the cavity is not at the centre!I get your point....

Comment: Your book told you the field was zero along the surface? Can you tell us exactly what your book argued? Because there is no way the E can come out of the integral unless it was constant over the entire Gaussian surface. So either your book is wrong, or you are interpreting something wrong.

Comment: Are you certain that the book doesn't simply state that the integral is equal to zero, and you falsely assumed this meant that the electric field was zero?

Comment: Yes you are correct.I made an wrong assumption.Thanks for the help!

Comment: So it turns out that for the case of charged spherical shells, the electric field outside is equal to the electric field you would have gotten from a point charge at the center with the same charge as the shell. But inside the shell, everywhere, the electric field cancels perfectly to zero. So, you could look at the charged sphere as being built by infinitely many infinitely thin shells, the fields of all of which cancel! This is why. But this is a special case. If the cavity isn't in the middle, it intersects some shells and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

$E=0$ is not true. Instead the surface integral of $E$ over the whole surface is zero, which makes sense as there is as much E-field leaving your surface as there is entering it (so it cancels to zero).